# Асинхронная загрузка виджета группы ВК

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, асинхронность

Уже пробовал - не работает:

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?151" async onload="VK.Widgets.Group('vk_groups',{mode: 3,width: '220'},20003922);"></script>
```

Также пытался через

```
window.vkAsyncInit = function() { // Настройки для Вконтакта
  VK.init({                       // инициализация
    apiId:       APPID,           // APPID это индефикатор вконтакта
    onlyWidgets: true
  });

  VK.Widgets.Like("DIVID", {      // Добавление кнопки "мне нравится" для элемента #DIVID
    type: "mini"
  });
};
```

также не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

всё оказалось просто, нужно было добавить  для вывода

```
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
```